# cgal the demo Polyhedron, the debugger Crashes in qscopedpointer.h

Tags: cgal, qt5.5, qscopedpointer

I haven't make  any change in this demo, and it works fine firstly.  But after lunch, I  ran it again, the debugger crashed, and  I got an error(below), the debugger reached this line in qscopedpointer.h:

> inline T *data() const
>
> {
>      return d;
>   }

### error:

### Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFDE604516A (Qt5Guid.dll) in Polyhedron_3.exe: 0xC000041D: Access violation reading location 0x00000004: an unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback.

stack trace  like this:

Qt5Guid.dll!QScopedPointer >::data() Line 135   C++
    Qt5Guid.dll!qGetPtrHelper            >>(const QScopedPointer > & p) Line 983   C++

Qt5Guid.dll!QScreen::d_func() Line 59   C++

Qt5Guid.dll!QScreen::geometry() Line 302    C++

qwindowsd.dll!QWindowsWindow::isFullScreen_sys() Line 1630  C++

qwindowsd.dll!QWindowsWindow::handleResized(int wParam) Line 1394   C++

qwindowsd.dll!QWindowsContext::windowsProc(HWND__ * hwnd, unsigned int message,
QtWindows::WindowsEventType et, unsigned __int64 wParam, __int64 lParam, __int64 * result) Line 1011    C++

qwindowsd.dll!qWindowsWndProc(HWND__ * hwnd, unsigned int message, unsigned __int64 
wParam, __int64 lParam) Line 1271   C++

qwindowsd.dll!qWindowsWndProc(HWND__ * hwnd, unsigned int message, unsigned __int64 wParam, __int64 lParam) Line 1280   C++

qwindowsd.dll!WindowCreationData::initialize(const QWindow * w, HWND__ * hwnd, bool frameChange, double opacityLevel) Line 707  C++

qwindowsd.dll!QWindowsWindow::setWindowFlags_sys(QFlags wt, 
unsigned int flags) Line 1571   C++

qwindowsd.dll!QWindowsWindow::setParent_sys(const QPlatformWindow * parent) Line 1294   C++

qwindowsd.dll!QWindowsWindow::setParent(const QPlatformWindow * newParent) Line 1260    C++

Qt5Guid.dll!QWindow::setParent(QWindow * parent) Line 614   C++

Qt5Widgetsd.dll!q_createNativeChildrenAndSetParent(const QWidget * parentWidget) Line 1377  C++

Qt5Widgetsd.dll!q_createNativeChildrenAndSetParent(const QWidget * parentWidget) Line 1382  C++

Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QWidgetPrivate::create_sys(unsigned __int64 window, bool initializeWindow, bool destroyOldWindow) Line 1481 C++

Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QWidget::create(unsigned __int64 window, bool initializeWindow, bool destroyOldWindow) Line 1321    C++

Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QWidget::setVisible(bool visible) Line 8060 C++

Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QWidget::show() Line 7671   C++

Polyhedron_3.exe!main(int argc, char * * argv) Line 51  C++

Polyhedron_3.exe!__tmainCRTStartup() Line 626   C

Polyhedron_3.exe!mainCRTStartup() Line 466  C

===============================

I have no idea what the issue is. I appreciate if anyone could give me some advise to solve this.
Thanks.

Comment: When do you have that? at startup?

Comment: it was at startup, and all the plugins I need in Polyhedron demo loaded successfully.

Comment: By the way, when I stoped  debugging, the window display an error:  "The debugger was unable to terminate one or more processes: [1832] Polyhedron_3.exe: Access is denied. The debugger may be unstable now. It is recommended that you save all files and exit."

Comment: Looks like a permission issue...

Comment: what does that mean, could you give me more info? thanks~

Comment: If you have the rights to read the demo files then maybe an antivirus software prevents the access or something like that.

Comment: I recompiled some other demoes, and they ran well. After that I ran Polyhedron demo again, it worked.... I don't know why....and I  hadnt make any changes at all....May this strange accident would not happen again,,, By the way, thank you guy!

Comment: what did you have at lunch?